# Controls have blank spaces when placed adjacent to each other in sapui5

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to create a UI with multiple tables adjacent to each other and chose to use horizontal layout. The code is shown below

```
var mainLayout = new sap.ui.layout.HorizontalLayout({
        id : "MainLayout", // sap.ui.core.ID
        width: "100%",
        allowWrapping : false, // boolean
        visible : true, // boolean
        tooltip : undefined, // sap.ui.core.TooltipBase
        dependents : [], // sap.ui.core.Control, since 1.19
        content :
        [ 
            /*new sap.ui.table.Table("table",{
                width : "30%"
            }),
            new sap.ui.commons.Panel({
                id : "Panel", // sap.ui.core.ID
                width : "70%", // sap.ui.core.CSSSize
                height : undefined, // sap.ui.core.CSSSize
                enabled : true, // boolean
                visible : true, // boolean

            // sap.ui.commons.Button
            })*/

            new sap.ui.table.Table("table",{
                width : "30%"
            }),
            new sap.ui.table.Table("table1",{
                width : "30%"
            }),
            new sap.ui.commons.Button("button1", {
                text: "Button1"
            }),
            new sap.ui.commons.Button("button2", {
                text: "Button2"
            }),
            new sap.ui.commons.Button("button3", {
                text: "Button3"
            })



        ]
    // sap.ui.core.Control
    })
    return mainLayout;
```

I can see after the UI is as shown in image
[image]

After the table there is huge space before the next table. How do i remove the blank space and make them appear next to each other.

Thanks,
Veera

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you have set the with of the tables using a percentage. It now takes 30% of the viewport width.

*(I assume your second table is just outside the visible viewport, and if you scroll just a little to the right it will be visible, right?)*

Although you have explicitly set the width of the HorizontalLayout to 100%, you didn't specify it for its parents (the `<div>`, `<body>` and `<html>` elements):

```
html, body {
  height: 100%
}

div#uiArea {
  height: 100%
}
```

Or, if you don't need a relative width for your tables, set the tables width in absolute pixels, this will render the HorizontalLayout content perfectly adjacent to each other as well

Comment: setting the absolute pixel values does the trick. I have a more generic question with respect to layouts in sapui5. I need to build up a screen like this
Table1 - width - x height- x
Table2 (below Table1) - width - x height -x
Table3 (next to table 1) width - x height -2x
Tried with all combinations of vertical and horizontal layouts .Just does not seem to work.

Comment: I suggest mark the answer as correct, and create a new question for your layout query, along with the code you wrote for the layout, as well as what goes wrong. That will help us to give a more precise answer